# Saber si existe un numero dentro de una variable

Tags: c#, oracle

En una variable guardo un numero que esta en mi BD Oracle puede ser 236578898 pero solo necesito saber si trae el 2365 para realizar una operacion, cuenta1 es donde guardo el numero

```
if (int.Parse(cuenta1) == 2365) {
    //int valor1 = Int.Parse(TBRete.Text) + Int.Parse(TBRetenAsum.Text) - Int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
    //TBTotal1.Text = valor1.ToString();
} else {

}
```

Comment: solo necesitas sabes los 4 primeros digitos ?

Comment: Si 2365 siempre estan al principio y solo necesito saber si existen dentro de la variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que la variable a verificar sea de tipo `string`, puede usar [`StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx):

Ejemplo:

```
string variable_a_validar = "236578898";

if (variable_a_validar.StartsWith("2365")) 
{
   // Agregue aquí la lógica.
}
```

Comment: Para utlizar este metodo no se necesita `Type: System.StringComparison` ?, segun la documentacion se requiere, y no habla de sobre carga de metodos como para decir que es opcionar  [https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms131452(v=vs.110).aspx], me disculpas si estoy equivocado.

Comment: @srJJ el segundo parámetro es opcional. He actualizado la respuesta para mostrar el uso del método `StartsWith` que tiene 1 parámetro. Gracias por el comentario. Saludos.

Comment: Bueno bro, de todas formas gracias, aprendi algo nuevo hoy xD...

Answer (score 1):

Si estas interesado que se validen ambas cosas, que este al inicio y que contenga la los numero completamente, te recomiendo utilizar la funcion [**IndexOf**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) por la cual es necesario convertir los `int` a `string`.

```
string c = cuenta1;

if(c.IndexOf("2365") == 0)
{
  // Ejecutamos la secuencia de instrucciones.
}
```

Espero te ayude.
Saludos.